# mu4e address autocomplete during compose needs to make context-sensitive selections

Tags: mu4e

When composing an email in mu4e, I make heavy use of autocompletion in the To: and Cc: lines.

Sometimes I have both a personal and work email address for the person I'm communicating with.

I'd like the autocompletion to select the appropriate email address - I guess the easiest way to do so, would be to base it on the context I have selected.

For example, if I am sending email from alice@work.com to Bob, I'd like the mail to go to bob@bobsjob.com.  Whereas if I'm sending email from alice@gmail.com, I'd like the mail to go to bob@home.com

Since I already have alice@work.com and alice@gmail.com configured in mu4e contexts, it seems that what is needed is to make autocompletion respect the context.

What do I need to do, to make mu4e email address autocompletion respect the context?

Comment: Might have luck asking on the mu4e google group https://groups.google.com/g/mu-discuss